# Подскажите как выполняется этот код?

Tags: javascript

подскажите как работает этот код не до конца понимаю

```js
let arr = [
 [1, 0, 0 , 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0 , 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0 , 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0 , 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0 , 0, 'exid'],
];

let x = 0;
let y = 0;

for (; x < arr[0].length - 1 || y < arr.length - 1; ) {
 arr[y][x] = 0;

 if (x < arr[0].length - 1) {
  x += 1;
 } else {
  y += 1;
 }
 arr[y][x] = 1;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: А кто писал код? Не Вы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это координаты x и y во время выполнения цикла

```
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[4, 0]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
```

Работает это просто.
Вот это условние `x < arr[0].length - 1 || y < arr.length - 1;`, как вы видите по выводу выше сначала проверяет первое условие, если он истинно, то вы попадаете в тело цикла. Если нет, то проверяется второе условие, если оно истинно, то вы попадаете в тело цикла.

Вот эта часть кода:

```
if (x < arr[0].length - 1) {
    x += 1;
} else {
    y += 1;
}
```

просто отвечает за то, какую координату увеличить. Если истинно первое условие, то **x**, если второе, то **y**.

Суть программы в том, что вы затираете старое значение в массиве нулем, а в новое - единицу.

Судя по тому, как проходит ваш цикл - в координату `[0][0]` вы запишете **0**, а в последнюю координату - **1**.

Comment: Спасибо очень хороший развернутый ответ мне только не понят почему arr[0].length - 1 а не просто arr[0].length